# json.loads fails with 'ascii' codec encoding error

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark

Need help in resolving below error, understand there are many solutions here to problems that throw such error. However, I have tried mostly all with little success.

> Error: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2026' in position 132:
>   ordinal not in range(128)

What I'm doing:
I'm trying to load JSON data using JSON.loads on a partition with data created by reading a file in `PySpark` as below. File has raw tweet in JSON format
data-file is created by another spark job by using `saveAsTextFile` with compression as bz2.

```
rdd1 = sc.textFile(datafile) 
#to get only the json portion of raw tweets
rdd2 = rdd1.map(lambda x : x[x.find('{'):len(x)])
```

Running a `mapPartitions` on rdd2 for processing text field of JSON data.

function definition looks something like this.

```
def func(raw_tweets):
  for records in raw_tweets: # record is of type 'str'
    try:
       record = record.decode('utf-8') # record now is a 'unicode' object 
       t = json.loads(record, encoding=('utf-8'))
       ....
   except:
        ...
```

this errors out with ascii' codec can't encode character.

Below are the possible work around I tried with no success.

- have tried with `use_unicode=False` while reading data with `sc.textFile`
- tried to encode "record" as encode('utf-8') also "ASCII" with and without ignore option
- tried loading the record as

  ```
  # to enforce record as type unicode, when read as str
  u_record = unicode(record) 
  t = json.loads(u_record)
  ```
- encode and decode and all above fails with same ascii encode error.

What I presume is happening is that JSON.loads implicitly tries to decode as ASCII before doing a Unicode encoding. 
could be reading something like this?

`str(u'\u2026')` as any encoding has no effect to this and fails with ASCII codec error

Could someone please help guide me and help understand how to make JSON.loads read data as Unicode encoding and not ASCII.
Thanks!

```
    json.loads('{"created_at":"Fri Apr 28 17:12:54 +0000 2017","id":858006119486062593,"id_str":"858006119486062593","text":"RT @richardgibson74: Rashid Khan fabulous to watch at the IPL again. Just one of the overseas players you won't be seeing in England's new\u2026","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/android\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for Android\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":2803663827,"id_str":"2803663827","name":"danesh bhopi","screen_name":"DaneshBhope","location":"Latur, India","url":null,"description":"4 Feb 1997  *wrestling* and *cricket*","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":170,"friends_count":352,"listed_count":30,"favourites_count":30781,"statuses_count":23038,"created_at":"Sat Oct 04 03:29:03 +0000 2014","utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":true,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"C0DEED","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"1DA1F2","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/790885528073744384\/o1Nen52M_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/790885528073744384\/o1Nen52M_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/2803663827\/1478675979","default_profile":true,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweeted_status":{"created_at":"Fri Apr 28 17:08:25 +0000 2017","id":858004991474372608,"id_str":"858004991474372608","text":"Rashid Khan fabulous to watch at the IPL again. Just one of the overseas players you won't be seeing in England's new T20 competition.","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter Web Client\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":57331172,"id_str":"57331172","name":"Richard Gibson","screen_name":"richardgibson74","location":"Leeds","url":"http:\/\/www.theguardian.com\/profile\/richard-gibson","description":"Football and cricket reporter; Daily Mail; Mail On Sunday; Guardian; Observer; Cricketer magazine; author of Bumble, Anderson, Root, Stokes and Swann books.","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":2880,"friends_count":198,"listed_count":97,"favourites_count":57,"statuses_count":5428,"created_at":"Thu Jul 16 13:16:51 +0000 2009","utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":true,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"C0DEED","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"1DA1F2","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/544621780363534336\/3_7ZOBvx_normal.jpeg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/544621780363534336\/3_7ZOBvx_normal.jpeg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/57331172\/1473706117","default_profile":true,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"retweet_count":1,"favorite_count":1,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en"},"is_quote_status":false,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"richardgibson74","name":"Richard Gibson","id":57331172,"id_str":"57331172","indices":[3,19]}],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en","timestamp_ms":"1493399574525"}',encoding=('utf-8'))
```

is one such record it fails to load with ascii encode error during json.loads (the position in error message may not be of this record!)

PS: Python version 2.7 on Spark 1.6

Comment: Can you add reproducible example?

Comment: added a record which fails to load with ascii codec error. Thanks!

Comment: Example you provided was broken(unescaped `'`). I fixed them, but still, i get `ValueError: Expecting , delimiter:` because of `\"`. When i fixed `\"` i didn't get any error at all.

Comment: Thank you. but, it still fails. Could you please elaborate a little more on delimiter error. This is the portion where it fails I suppose - `json.loads('{"source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/android\"}')`
I tried to do `.replace(r'\"',r'\\"')` but still not able to get around delimiter error. I would not be able to transform the whole string as raw string as the data is in an identifier.

Comment: I figured it out. The issue was not with json.loads, for debugging was writing the incoming data onto a file and it was failing there by trying to encode unicode chars into str(ascii), sorry for overlooking this, appreciate the time and suggestion